# MPNowPlayingInfoCenter nowPlayingInfo not shown while playing Video in an AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, airplay, mpnowplayinginfocenter

I am working on an app that has Video streaming.
I use AVPlayer to stream the videos, on the device or using AirPlay.
When you use AirPlay, you can lock the screen and the video continues playing.
On the home screen of your device you'll get the controls: a scrub bar, play/pause, backward/forward.

All good. Now I want to display some information about the video that is playing.
I read a lot about the MPNowPlayingInfoCenter and all looks pretty straight forward.
However, when I set the nowPlayingInfo, nothing gets set on the home screen.

I am clueless what I am doing wrong.
Do I have a setting in the AVPlayer that doesn't allow me to do this?
Is the timing I set the playingInfo wrong? (I tried to set it before playing, after loading the stream, after starting the stream, etc.)

This code below gets executed, but it does not set the nowPlayingInfo on the lock screen:

```
 MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter().nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "My Video Title"]
```

Comment: Do the video and audio currently play correctly through AirPlay with the screen locked? How did you configure `AVAudioSession`? Do you ever call  `UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()`?

Comment: Yes, it all plays correctly. I do call ```UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()``` indeed before I update the ```MPNowPlayingInfoCenter```.

Comment: I'm having an issue where setting `nowPlayingInfo` only sometimes updates the lock screen.  I've found that putting a breakpoint on the line that sets it (the line of code you included) makes sure it always updates.  I can't explain why but maybe give that a shot?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **AVPlayerViewController** to show a video playing in app. It would take **AVPlayer**. Then you can set AVPlayerViewController's **updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter** to **false**.

```
    let playerController = AVPlayerViewController()
    var player: AVPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(string: "url_string")!)
    playerController.player = player
    playerController.updatesNowPlayingInfoCenter = false
    present(playerController, animated: true) {
        player.play()
    }
```

Also, you need to set MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().**nowPlayingInfo** to information you want to show.

Comment: This solved my issue partially, but setting the MPNowPlayingInfo does not update anything, actually now the NowPlayingInfo doesn't appear at all even after setting `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)`